# Force end user browser to forget old SSL - Caching & Secure Pages

Tags: nginx, ssl, cache

**Problem**

I recently switched the domain of my website. websiteA.com to websiteB.com

(Stack: LEMP, running memcache and Varnish for caching.)

I set up nginx to 403 re-direct everything and on new computers that all works fine.

The only problem comes with users who logged in over SSL on the old address. If they go to https://websiteA.com then it re-directs to https://websiteB.com, but the browser having cached something (possibly the certificate) warns them that they're being re-directed from websiteA to websiteB with the horrible yellow warning page.

On new computers it all works fine. Is there some sort of signal I can send (like a cache expire header or something) which will force the browsers to drop the old SSL and pick up a new one?

Comment: What is exactly the "horrible yellow warning page"? What is the exact problem the browser has with the redirect?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen It's this [one](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ffssl.png) in Firefox or this [one](http://i.imgur.com/uL2KCcj.png) in Chrome (however the background is yellow.)

Comment: Can you show the Technical details part of the warning?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Ok [here it is](https://www.flickr.com/photos/86849256@N05/13465619673), the problem really is this only appears on computers who've tried to visit the old SSL certificate, on new computers it re-directs then checks the SSL not vice versa.